# Does HashMap provide a one to one correspondence?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I found the following statement:

> Map is an object that stores
>   key/volume pairs. Given a key, you can
>   find its value. Keys must be unique,
>   but values may be duplicated.

For example I have just one key/value pair (3,4). And now I `put` a new pair (3,5). It will remove the old pair. Right? But if I `put` (2,4) instead of (3,4) I will add a new pair of key/value to the HashMap. Right?

Comment: Have you ever tried to do some debugging/testing yourself?

Comment: Never hurts to *experiment*, unless you are playing leap frog with a unicorn, don't experiment with that, it'll end badly..

Comment: Anthony: Also, questions that begin, "I wonder if the government would object if I did my taxes this way ..." are best resolved by consulting a lawyer rather than experimenting. The IRS shows a distressing lack of appreciation for creativity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the first number in the parentheses is the Key, you can think of it as the address. The second is the Value. The Key is unique, just like your home's address, but the Value can be anything.

Answer (score 10):

The answer to the question in your title is "No". The answer to the question in your message is "Yes". If you want a bidirectional map with unique keys and unique values as asked in your title (also called a key-key map), have a look at [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) [BiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html).

Answer (score 2):

You are correct.  For each key there is only one value.  But it is nothing to prevent multiple keys to have the same value.

Think of the HashMap like it is a box of drawers,  each drawer can hold only one object and each drawer is marked with the key.   So after you put an apple in drawer marked 1 you can't put an orange in there, unless you take out an apple from there first.  However,  nothing stops you from putting oranges in drawers 2 3 and 4.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's correct. If you want a one-to-one correspondence, use something like [BiMap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) from [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) (or [Google's Java Collections library](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/)).